# MVC v2 preview 2, Is it stable enough for production use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is anyone out there using MVC v2 preview 2 out in production yet?
Can anyone make comments whether this version is good enough/or they have used this for use in production code?

Should I stick with version 1 and wait for the official release?

Comment: Beta was just released http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/asp.net-mvc-2-beta-released.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're not in production with it yet, but in development and testing almost since the day it was released we haven't found any regressions yet.

Answer (score 0):

We would never put beta s/ware into production.  I guess it all depends on your line of business but a public facing site is too important to leave in the hands of beta software no matter how far along it is.

If I found that the final release was going to be in a couple of months, then I might be tempted to begin coding against it but it wouldn't go any further than the test environment until it was out of beta.

Would you put a beta version of your code into production?

Comment: Short answer no I wouldn't, I have a large project that I will still be working on in 6 months and want to know if I should start using MVC 2 or stick with 1....

Comment: I think 6 months is a pretty safe bet on it being out by then.  Still a bit os a risk but given the time line, one I might be inclined to take.